# why would there be a load of 5 if there are zero processes in the runq?

Tags: kernel, load

This doesn't make sense to me, why would there be a load of 5 if there are zero processes in the runq?

```
12:00:01 AM   runq-sz  plist-sz   ldavg-1   ldavg-5  ldavg-15
12:05:01 AM         0       708      5.23      5.14      5.10
12:15:01 AM         0       708      5.16      5.12      5.09
12:25:01 AM         0       708      5.07      5.07      5.08
12:35:01 AM         0       708      5.12      5.08      5.07
12:45:01 AM         2       708      5.18      5.15      5.09
12:55:01 AM         1       708      5.05      5.12      5.09
01:05:01 AM         0       708      5.06      5.08      5.08
01:15:01 AM         0       708      5.14      5.11      5.09
```

I know iowait is often the culprit for driving up the reported load, but there's very little disk activity,

```
12:00:01 AM       DEV       tps  rd_sec/s  wr_sec/s  avgrq-sz  avgqu-sz     await     svctm     %util
12:05:01 AM    dev8-0      1.53      0.00     30.61     20.01      0.00      0.34      0.21      0.03
12:15:01 AM    dev8-0      1.32      0.00     25.77     19.51      0.00      0.34      0.10      0.01
12:25:01 AM    dev8-0      1.60      0.00     40.81     25.43      0.00      0.64      0.29      0.05
12:35:01 AM    dev8-0      1.64      0.00     35.76     21.80      0.00      0.73      0.22      0.04
12:45:01 AM    dev8-0      1.33      0.00     25.95     19.51      0.00      0.23      0.12      0.02
```

The box itself is running a django instance and handling about 5 hits/sec.

Comment: How many CPUs do you have in that machine?

Comment: What's `ps -Leo state,pid,args | grep '^[RD]'` telling you? Uninterruptible processes are counted in there.

Answer (score 2):

> What's ps -Leo state,pid,args | grep '^[RD]' telling you? 
>   Uninterruptible processes are counted in there.

Aha! That's the answer, I'd quite forgotten about that.

```
D    59 [kacpi_notify]
D 24806 [power_saving/0]
D 24807 [power_saving/1]
D 24808 [power_saving/2]
D 24809 [power_saving/3]
```

That's five processes, and my load is five.

From 'man uptime':

> System load averages is the average number of processes that are 
>   either in a runnable **or uninterruptable state.**

I should have remembered that. Thanks, Stephane Chazelas!

Comment: You seem to have accidentally created two accounts; see [this page](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for how to have them merged.